# Entity Framework Spatial Query Throws Null Reference Exception

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq, spatial

I've got some records that I'm trying to query with EF 6 based on distance.  I've got a geography column and have used the DbGeography classes in .NET.  I'm getting a Null Reference Exception when I execute the query.  Ideas?

*Method*

```
public IList<Location> GetAllByCoordinates(double longitude, double latitude, double distance)
    {
        var geoPoint = DbGeography.PointFromText($"POINT({longitude} {latitude})", 4326);

        return _repo.GetAll()
            .Select(l => new Location
            {
                Id = l.Id,
                Longitude = l.Longitude,
                Latitude = l.Latitude,
                Elevation = l.Elevation,
                Distance = l.Geography.Distance(geoPoint).Value
            }).ToList();
    }
```

*Error Stack*

> at KittyHawk.Domain.Services.LocationService.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.b__0(LocationEntity l) in D:\Development\manteo\KittyHawk.Domain\Services\LocationService.cs:line 40
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
>      at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>      at KittyHawk.Domain.Services.LocationService.GetAllByCoordinates(Double longitude, Double latitude, Double distance) in D:\Development\manteo\KittyHawk.Domain\Services\LocationService.cs:line 39
>      at KittyHawk.Controllers.LocationController.GetNearbyLocations(Double longitude, Double latitude, Double distance) in D:\Development\manteo\KittyHawk\Controllers\LocationController.cs:line 39
>      at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
>      at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)
>      at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object instance, Object[] arguments)
>      at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check to make sure geoPoint isn't a null. then, make sure that all of your location points have a long/lat. I have a feeling that you have some locations in your database that doing have them?

Comment: geoPoint is not null, it has a value once created.  In addition every location in the DB has a geography field.

Comment: Actually on further inspection, we somehow got a single null record in the table and that caused the query to fail.  Go figure.